# Drupal 7 Custom Content Type - Created content does not appear in CONTENT list

Tags: drupal

EDIT:  Content is created by *administrator* user with full priveleges.  The content type is nothing special (minimum changes when creating new content type).  The content created shows up in Workbench but not in Content.  The cache has been cleared so many times I think the button is getting worn down.

I created a new custom content type for testing purposes and created a few nodes of said type. When I go back to my list of content, I see the pages that were in the before, but none of my content type.

For example, I have 1 Web form type and 4 of type Basic Page. There are 3 nodes created of Odd Content type, but they are not shown in that list, and if I filter for "Odd Content" there are no results.

How do I fix this?

EDIT:

[It appears in WORKBENCH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNBbK.png)
[It does NOT appear in content list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scMKW.png)

Comment: The details are insufficient. You did not mention how did you create the content type. You also did not mention whether those content are published and what user you are logged in with.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing all the caches. Some stuff with drupal are heavy cached.

Comment: Hello again, Milan!

I've cleared the caches into oblivion.  It's strange (or maybe it isn't?) that everything shows up fine in Workbench, but not in Content.